# Kendo UI RadialGauge add custom tool-tip on pointer

Tags: kendo-ui, gauge

I want to show the current value of chart into the pointer tool-tip, If there any way to add tool-tip please suggest, please check [gauge screenshot](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/920997/bfd9d455cff76938b0469be1eea537eb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in method for this afaik.  So you can use the kndoUI tooltip object like this:

In the gauge config, I assign a unique CSS color to the pointer so I can easily query for the SVG element

```
$("#gauge").kendoRadialGauge({
    pointer: {
        value: $("#gauge-value").val(),
        color: "rgba(255,102,0,.999)"
    },
    scale: {
        minorUnit: 5,
        startAngle: -30,
        endAngle: 210,
        max: 180
    }
});
```

Then setup the tooltip widget so that onShow, the content is set to the current value of the gauge. The filter attribute points at any dom object with our unique fill color.

```
var tooltip = $('#gauge').kendoTooltip({
    filter: '[fill="rgba(255,102,0,.999)"]',
    position: "center",
    content: $("#gauge").data("kendoRadialGauge").value(),
    show: function(e) {
      e.sender.options.content = $("#gauge").data("kendoRadialGauge").value();
      e.sender.refresh();
    }
}).data("kendoTooltip");
```

Here is a dojo **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/AKEwA)**

Comment: I haven't tried but I think this strategy wouldn't work if you have multiple pointers of the same color, would it?

Comment: Ok. This strategy could potentially work. Usually the `pointer.cap.color` is the same with the `pointer.color`. We don't want the tooltip shown when the mouse pointer is over the `pointer.cap`. So we make the selector more specific, something like `path[fill="rgba(255,102,0,.999)"][stroke="rgba(255,102,0,.999)"]`. Good enough.

Comment: @jpllosa - you can also use different opacity for each pointer. just change the third, fourth, fifth digit so the colors appear the same on the screen. e.g rgba(255,102,0,.9999), rgba(255,102,0,.998), rgba(255,102,0,.997)